# Calculator displaying

Tags: javascript

I am trying to make a calculator for money in a game. I am unable to display  variables, though I think im using the proper methods.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var score;
var kr;
var place;
var result;
window.addEventListener('load', onDocLoaded, false);

function onDocLoaded(evt){
    document.getElementById('myButton').addEventListener('click', krCalc, false);
}
function krCalc() {
    if (place === 1 && score > 0){
        kr = (score/150) * 1.5;
        console.log("A score of "+score+"pts gets you "+kr+" KR while in place "+place+".");
        document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "Result: A score of "+score+"pts gets you "+kr+" KR while in place "+place+".";

    }
    if (place === 2 && score > 0){
        kr = (score/150) * 1.2;
        console.log("A score of "+score+"pts gets you "+kr+" KR while in place "+place+".");
        document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "Result: A score of "+score+"pts gets you "+kr+" KR while in place "+place+".";

    }
    if (place >= 3 && score > 0) {
        kr = (score/150);
        console.log("A score of "+score+"pts gets you "+kr+" KR while in place "+place+".");
        document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "Result: A score of "+score+"pts gets you "+kr+" KR while in place "+place+".";
    }
    while (kr>10){
        kr = 10;
    }
}
  </script>

  <style type="text/css">

  </style>

</head>

<body>
    <form>
        Place<br>
        <input type="text" name="place" autocomplete="off"><br>
        Score<br>
        <input type="text" name="score" autocomplete="off">
        <input id="myButton" type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>
    <p id="result">Result:</p>
</body>

</html>
```

I would add more to this post though I have no idea what is going on, and have been around the internet trying to figure out how to properly do this. When the submit button is hit it refreshes the page for some reason, I have no idea why.

Comment: Are the log messages showing up in the console?

Comment: Yes they were nathen, I got the console messages worked before I worked with displaying it.

Answer (score 1):

An input with `type="submit"` is used for submitting forms. Changing this to `type="button"` will stop the page from submitting/refreshing.

Answer (score 0):

> When the submit button is hit it refreshes the page for some reason, I
>   have no idea why.

It will normally refreshes the page because the submit button will trigger the form to submit. An ordinary form looks like this below:

```
<form class="" action="index.php" method="post">

</form>
```

But since you didn't put any attribute in your `<form>` tag, logically the value of your `action` would be the current page, which means that if you submit your form, you will land on your page again and again.

**If you don't want your form to submit,** do not use `type="submit"`. Use `type="button"` instead. Or to make that simple, you can also remove your `<form>` tag.

Comment: Thanks, I am now using a button type.

Answer (score 0):

type="submit" it's a special type of a button which tries to send an http-request. That's the reason why your site is loading.

try this:

```
<button onclick="myFunction()">Click me</button>
```

Comment: And plz add a console.log("your string") directly after this "function krCalc() {". So that you can check if your function will be executed

Answer (score 0):

### Update

The `score` and `place` variables are never updated, so the if statements will never run. You need to update the variables when the form is submitted. Try adding this at the top of your `krCalc` function:

```
place = document.getElementsByName('place')[0].value;
score = document.getElementsByName('score')[0].value;
```

### Original Answer

As others said, the form is being submitted. The form's action is the current page by default, which reloads the page.

It is better to listen for the form's `submit` event (rather than just the submit button click) as it will also catch pressing enter when focused on a field:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var score;
var kr;
var place;
var result;
window.addEventListener('load', onDocLoaded, false);

function onDocLoaded(evt){
    document.getElementById('myForm').addEventListener('submit', krCalc);
}
function krCalc(evt) {
    evt.preventDefault(); // this prevents the form from causing page refresh

    if (place === 1 && score > 0){
        kr = (score/150) * 1.5;
        console.log("A score of "+score+"pts gets you "+kr+" KR while in place "+place+".");
        document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "Result: A score of "+score+"pts gets you "+kr+" KR while in place "+place+".";

    }
    if (place === 2 && score > 0){
        kr = (score/150) * 1.2;
        console.log("A score of "+score+"pts gets you "+kr+" KR while in place "+place+".");
        document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "Result: A score of "+score+"pts gets you "+kr+" KR while in place "+place+".";

    }
    if (place >= 3 && score > 0) {
        kr = (score/150);
        console.log("A score of "+score+"pts gets you "+kr+" KR while in place "+place+".");
        document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "Result: A score of "+score+"pts gets you "+kr+" KR while in place "+place+".";
    }
    while (kr>10){
        kr = 10;
    }
}
  </script>
```

And add the ID to the form:

```
<form id="myForm">
...
</form>
```

With this option, you would leave the button's `type` as a submit so the button will still submit the form. When the form submits (by either clicking this button or pressing enter while focused on a field), the JavaScript listener callback will fire. Calling `preventDefault` on the event object prevents the default action of the form submit event.

Comment: @ImCasperr Your question seemed to be about the page refreshing. Should make it more clear that you're having trouble make it display. I'll add some info to my answer about that issue. Also, I recommend using this method instead of making the button `type="button"` as it's better practice.